# Inspecting Websockets in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

In chrome, In the network tab I can see my WS request, and then the frames, but how to know who is the sender, theorgin : the server or the client ?

Comment: You can use Fiddler for debugging websocket, which will show you the direction of each frame. I have recently written an article on CodeProject, which show you how to debug/inspect WebSocket traffic with Fiddler. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718660/Debug-Inspect-WebSocket-traffic-with-Fiddler

Answer (score 1):

That level of detail / information is not available in Chrome Inspector (not even in Chrome Canary 34.x)

Would recommend using Wireshark to capture the raw frames (but be aware that Wireshark does not yet support deflate-frame or permessage-deflate websocket extensions.  Chrome supports it, and some servers do too.)